# Command Not Supported for auto encryption when using spring boot actuator with mongodb client-side field-level encryption

Tags: mongodb, encryption, spring-data-mongodb, spring-boot-actuator

I am using MongoDB Auto Client-Side Field-Level Encryption in a Spring Boot application. To expose health-check, the spring-boot-actuator is also a dependency. I am providing a `schemaMap()` to `AutoEncryptionSettings` while constructing `MongoClient`. The normal encryption works fine and the fields of the collection are encrypted, however when the health-check is hit, the following exception occurs:

```
org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Exception in encryption library: command not supported for auto encryption: buildInfo; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoClientException: Exception in encryption library: command not supported for auto encryption: buildInfo
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MongoExceptionTranslator.java:138) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.potentiallyConvertRuntimeException(MongoTemplate.java:2902) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.execute(MongoTemplate.java:560) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeCommand(MongoTemplate.java:476) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.mongo.MongoHealthIndicator.doHealthCheck(MongoHealthIndicator.java:46) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.AbstractHealthIndicator.health(AbstractHealthIndicator.java:82) [spring-boot-actuator-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicator.getHealth(HealthIndicator.java:37) [spring-boot-actuator-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointWebExtension.getHealth(HealthEndpointWebExtension.java:95) [spring-boot-actuator-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointWebExtension.getHealth(HealthEndpointWebExtension.java:43) [spring-boot-actuator-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getContribution(HealthEndpointSupport.java:108) [spring-boot-actuator-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getAggregateHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:119) [spring-boot-actuator-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getContribution(HealthEndpointSupport.java:105) [spring-boot-actuator-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:83) [spring-boot-actuator-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:70) [spring-boot-actuator-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointWebExtension.health(HealthEndpointWebExtension.java:81) [spring-boot-actuator-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointWebExtension.health(HealthEndpointWebExtension.java:70) [spring-boot-actuator-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor78.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:282) [spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.invoke.reflect.ReflectiveOperationInvoker.invoke(ReflectiveOperationInvoker.java:77) [spring-boot-actuator-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.AbstractDiscoveredOperation.invoke(AbstractDiscoveredOperation.java:60) [spring-boot-actuator-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$ServletWebOperationAdapter.handle(AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping.java:305) [spring-boot-actuator-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping.java:388) [spring-boot-actuator-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor77.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) [spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) [spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) [spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879) [spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) [spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) [spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) [spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) [spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) [spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) [spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) [spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.ShallowEtagHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ShallowEtagHeaderFilter.java:106) [spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) [spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126) [spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) [spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118) [spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) [spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158) [spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) [spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) [spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:92) [spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92) [spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77) [spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) [spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) [spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) [spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) [spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) [spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:109) [spring-boot-actuator-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) [spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
    at com.finzy.commons.web.filter.HttpRequestResponseLoggingFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpRequestResponseLoggingFilter.java:43) [commons-web-0.0.81.jar!/:?]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1594) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
```

**Edit:** This might be happening because `MongoHealthIndicator` used when health-check is hit executes `this.mongoTemplate.executeCommand("{ buildInfo: 1 }");` which according to [MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/security-client-side-query-aggregation-support/) is not a supported command when using client-side encryption.

> Issuing any other command through a 4.2-compatible driver configured
>   for automatic client-side field-level encryption returns an error.

Is there any way I can still achieve health-check using spring actuator or would I have to get rid of spring-boot-actuator for the service?

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I could just disable the `MongoHealthIndicator` check by putting `management.health.mongo.enabled=false` in `application.properties`. Hope spring-boot-actuator or mongo driver with CSFLE enabled gets an update soon and starts supporting each other.

Answer (score 0):

Update to at least `org.mongodb:mongodb-crypt:1.5.1`.

According to this [JIRA ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/MONGOCRYPT-308), the `buildInfo` command (as used by the health check) needs to be `allow-listed` as not requiring auto encryption.